# Not sure what i am missing with this assignment

Tags: frontend, visual-web-developer

This is what i am asked to do

1. Open the `styles.css` file.
2. Add a CSS rule for the `body` element that sets the background color to `#E0E0E2`.
3. Add a CSS rule for the `h1` element that sets the text color to: `#721817`.
4. Add a CSS rule for the `h2` element that sets the text color to: `#721817`.
5. Add a CSS rule for the `center-text` CSS class that aligns the text to `center`.
6. Add a CSS rule for the HTML element with the id `logo`. Set its left and right margins to `auto` and changes its display to a `block` element.
7. Add a CSS rule for all `span` elements that are children of `h2` elements that sets the text color to `#FA9F42` and its font size to `0.75em`.
8. Add a CSS rule for the HTML element with the id `copyright`. Set its top padding to `12` pixels and its font size to `0.75em`.

this is what i did

body{background-color:#e0e0e2;}
`h1{color:#721817;}` h2{color:#721817;}
`center-text{text-align: center;}` logo{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;} h2>span{color:#fa9f42;font-size:0.75em;}
`copyright{padding-top:12px;font-size:0.75em;}`

this is what i need to fix but im not sure how to properly adjust it

✗ All elements with the 'center-text' class should have center-aligned text
✗ The element with the ID 'logo' should have a display of 'block' (+ 2 related tests)
✗ The element with the ID 'copyright' should have a padding-top of 12px

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/505191